# firebase android how to get current user information from database?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im new with firebase I don't know how to show firebase current user information in my profile activity java this is my current code

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            showData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        DataUser uinfo = new DataUser();

        uinfo.SetName(ds.child(Userid).getValue(DataUser.class).name);
        uinfo.SetDOB(ds.child(Userid).getValue(DataUser.class).name);


    }
}
```

And this is my dataview java for the setter getter

```
public class DataUser {

String name, DOB;

public DataUser(){
}

public void SetName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void SetDOB(String DOB){
    this.DOB = DOB;
}
public String getDOB(){
    return DOB;
}

}
```

My question is my code correct? And I got text view for both name and dob but I don't know how to make them show the userinformation that I already call in my code?

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3fxu5xmjsdkfpfn/S__17350661.jpg?dl=0 here is my database

Answer (score 0):

You can get user data from the `firebaseUser` object like this:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
    String email = firebaseUser.getEmail();
    String name = firebaseUser.getDisplayName();

    editText.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: hmm i want to make the current user name and dob show in their own edittext do you know how?

Comment: Please use: `editText.setText(getName(());` and `editText.setText(getDOB());`

Comment: Have you figure it out?

Comment: sry for the long respond. i tried to use settext for my code
but it didnt seems to work. if i use your code i didnt understand do i need to use datapost again or not? and i cant seem to change getemail to getDOB?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You don't need to use `dataSnapshot` object to get the desired data. Also please see the [offical doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) regarding `FirebaUser` class.